# How to use append() with sortable, connectwith in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create drag and drop-able contents with the help of jQuery.

```
<div id="sortable1" class="ui-helper-reset">
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 1</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 2</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 3</div>
</div>
<div id="trash"></div>
```

JQuery code

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: '#trash'
});
$("#trash").sortable({
    connectWith: '#sortable1'
});
```

How to add (append) a html resource into that ".ui-state-default" div only after  i dropped in to that trash div.   thanks in advance

Comment: As in, replace the one you trashed with a new item? Item 4?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting you correctly, modify your `#trash.sortable` method to be like this

```
$("#trash").sortable({
    connectWith: '#sortable1',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        $("#sortable1").append('<div class="ui-state-default">New Item</div>');
    }
});
```

The `receive` function is called whenever you drop an element into the trash div.